# File upload from a WPF application

Tags: .net, wcf, rest, file-upload, httphandler

I have to upload file from a WPF application to the server. Following are the methods i tried

1. HTTPHandler
2. WCF
3. REST

Any idea which one would be better and faster? The application is hosted on .Net 4.0 ,IIS 6

Comment: How much data are you transferring and what are the speeds you are getting and hoping for?

Comment: Data transfer can be of any size, i know maximum supported is 2 gb at a time but user can send anything. Speed is max supported by server and network.

Comment: Depends on your server. Whichever is easier on the server end. If you are building it only for communication with your wpf app. then WCF is the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If faster means better, you should be using the mechanism with the least overhead. I would expect that to be WCF or REST streamed mode.

If security and reliability is of importance, you should consider a buffered/chunked mode instead.